# How to calculate price of the hotel room in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I need to Create a worksheet which calculates the rate of an hotel room according to high and low
season, and the number of days of stay.
There is a 5% discount per week of stay, with a maximum limit of 20%
What formula should I put inside total? I am a complete noob and just started learning it today.
B1:C1 are named Seasons, B2:C6 are named Rates, A2:A6 named Discounts

Comment: What have you tried and where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the table. Assuming the max discount is applied to each day and the discount starts after 7 days, your formula would look like:

```
=LET(
    Discount, 5%,
    Season, F2,
    Nights, G2,

    Weeks, FLOOR(Nights/7,1),
    TotalDiscount, MIN(Discount*Weeks),
    LowHighIndex, MATCH(Season,$A$1:$C$1,0),
    Rate, INDEX($A$2:$C$2,1,LowHighIndex),

    TotalPrice, Nights*Rate,
    TotalPrice
)
```